# Load balance node js application with single Kafka consumer

Tags: apache-kafka

I have built one node js application using single Kafka topic with one partition. When I have to consume too many messages with low latency, CPU usage is very high and the application crashes. How can I avoid this ? As I can not deploy multiple instances of my application to distribute the load. Reason is because I have a single Kafka topic and single partition. For a reason, I can not have multiple partitions or topics.

Comment: Why can you not enforce more than one partition? You cannot distribute otherwise.

Comment: Ok. Let us assume I used multiple partitions. And if I have a cluster of three nodejs applications running. 
Nodejs instance 1
Nodejs instance 2
Nodejs instance 3

At any point a single consumer (assume consumer of Nodejs instance1) will consume the messages from a kafka queue partition. Consumers in the other instances (nodejs instance2 & 3) will be idle. With very high volume of messages being consumed by nodejs instance 1, this will cause high cpu right ? Though I have a cluster of node js instances running.